# Deploying Flask to Vercel for NLP model

Tags: python, flask, vercel

I'm running the following flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import en_core_web_sm
from rules import *

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/api/rule1', methods=['POST'])
def process_text_r1():
    try:
        text = request.json.get('text', '')

        if not text:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Text not provided'}), 400

        result = rule1(nlp,text)
        return jsonify({'result': result})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Internal server error', 'message': str(e)}), 500
```

It runs well on localhost. When I deploy it Vercel, I get the error:

*Error: The Serverless Function "api/app" is 53.78mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb. Learn More: https://vercel.link/serverless-function-size*

The link above says: The maximum size for a Serverless Function is 50 MB and the maximum unzipped size is 250 MB including layers which are automatically used depending on Runtimes.

**I want to be able to deploy the app without exceeding size limits. What can I do?**

I have tried locating the model, but it's just a bunch of files in:

`C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\`

I was expecting it to be larger than 50MB, but the model is just 15.3MB. I wonder where the application is bloating at?